# java.lang.StackOverflowError in ANdroid

Tags: android, android-layout

I get java.lang.StackOverflowError when I call an activity from an activitygroup.

Following is the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(PermissionsScreen.this,DownloadActivity.class);
replaceContentView("Activity10",i);
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView();
this.setContentView(view);
    }
```

I do not get the java.lang.StackOverflowError  when I call a different activity in place of DownloadActivity.class, as shown

```
Intent i = new Intent(PermissionsScreen.this,PaymentScreen.class);
replaceContentView("Activity10",i);
```

The difference between PaymentScreen and DownloadActivity in first observation is that, PaymentScreen is a simple activity. Whereas DownloadActivity uses asynctask for downloading files.

What causes StackOverflowError to occur when I launch one activity and does not occur in another case?

I am unable to find any obvious reasons for the same.

Any help is appreciated.

```
05-15 12:38:11.906: WARN/audio_hw_primary(135): select_output_device e=0, h=0, s=2, b=0
05-15 12:38:11.953: INFO/dalvikvm(6119): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/text/TextLine;.handleText:FLIIIIZLFIIILZ
05-15 12:38:11.953: INFO/dalvikvm(6119):   method requires 164+20+40=224 bytes, fp is 0x56c9b36c (108 left)
05-15 12:38:11.953: INFO/dalvikvm(6119):   expanding stack end (0x56c9b300 to 0x56c9b000)
05-15 12:38:11.953: INFO/dalvikvm(6119): Shrank stack (to 0x56c9b300, curFrame is 0x56c9b88c)
05-15 12:38:11.953: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(6119): Shutting down VM
05-15 12:38:11.953: WARN/dalvikvm(6119): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b1a1f8)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119): java.lang.StackOverflowError
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1021)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:470)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:315)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:289)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:949)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:409)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:400)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5004)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10880)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10319)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1655)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10319)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10319)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10317)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10319)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2862)
05-15 12:38:11.968: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6119):     
05-15 12:38:12.046: WARN/ActivityManager(261):   Force finishing activity com.nykkos.personalize/.profiler.Personalization
05-15 12:38:12.109: INFO/WindowManager(261): createSurface Window{424e87a0  paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
05-15 12:38:12.117: DEBUG/dalvikvm(6119): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1265K, 8% free 17457K/18823K, paused 8ms+14ms
```

Given below is the layout of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout_downloading"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/total_progress" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/all_download_downloading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:indeterminateOnly="false"
        android:maxHeight="10dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit_btn_downloading"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/exit_back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/download_btn_downloading"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/start_download" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Given below is the layout of the adapter which I use in DownloadActivity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLink"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/green_progress_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPercent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="0%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: Look at the Stacktrace (and post it here). You probably end up calling a method recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your stack trace, you have a huge nested view hierarchy that tries to draw itself.

Either it's an insanely deep hierarchy, or maybe you programatically build\inflate child views inside your `ViewGroup`, and end up creating a recursive view containment.

Either way, it doesn't seem related to the code you posted, but to the actual UI content of the problematic activity.

If you don't find the problem in the activity layout (which seems pretty obvious from that stack trace), please post your layout XML or your layout code in your question.

Comment: added the layout as requested. what need to be done to resolve this?

Comment: Your layout seems ordinary. You didn't post the complete layout, because you have ScrollView and RelativeLayout tags at the end. What about the problematic activity code? Where exactly does it crash?

Comment: Also, I didn't understand what were you trying to do with replaceContentView(). You start another activity, get its root view and try to set it as your current content view? That looks like getting into trouble...