# how to solve java.lang.StackOverflowError from BadgeView class

Tags: android, badge

i am using this BadgeView class to create badge in calendar event date..first time its run but when goes to next month BadgeView class it gives stackoverflow error..
badgeView class calling by this and badge appy on linearlayout

```
badge = new BadgeView(context, event_dateview_layout);
                    badge.setText("" + eventno.size());
                    Log.d("aa", "eventno:" + eventno);
                    badge.show();


BadgeView.java

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RoundRectShape;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BadgeView extends TextView {

    private Context context;
    private View target;
    private ShapeDrawable badgeBg;

    public BadgeView(Context context, View target) {

        this(context, null, android.R.attr.textViewStyle, target);
    }

    public BadgeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, View target) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, target);
    }

    private void init(Context context, View target) {

        this.context = context;
        this.target = target;

        //apply defaults
        setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        setPadding(7, 0, 7, 0);
        setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        if (this.target != null) {
            applyTo(this.target);
        } else {
            show();
        }

    }

    private void applyTo(View target) {

        LayoutParams lp = target.getLayoutParams();
        ViewParent parent = target.getParent();
        FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(context);

        // TODO verify that parent is indeed a ViewGroup
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) parent;
        int index = group.indexOfChild(target);

        group.removeView(target);
        group.addView(container, index, lp);
        container.addView(target);
        container.addView(this);
        group.invalidate();

    }

    public void show() {

        if (getBackground() == null) {
            if (badgeBg == null) {
                badgeBg = getDefaultBackground();
            }
            setBackgroundDrawable(badgeBg);
        }
        applyLayoutParams();
    }

    private ShapeDrawable getDefaultBackground() {

        float[] outerR = new float[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20};
        RoundRectShape rr = new RoundRectShape(outerR, null, null);
        ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(rr);
        drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        return drawable;
    }

    private void applyLayoutParams() {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

 java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at android.view.HardwareCanvas.<init>(HardwareCanvas.java:29)
            at android.view.GLES20Canvas.<init>(GLES20Canvas.java:100)
            at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.<init>(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:62)
            at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.<init>(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:38)
            at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas$1.newInstance(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:46)
            at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas$1.newInstance(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:44)
            at android.util.FinitePool.acquire(FinitePool.java:69)
            at android.util.SynchronizedPool.acquire(SynchronizedPool.java:39)
            at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.obtain(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:66)
            at android.view.GLES20DisplayList.start(GLES20DisplayList.java:67)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12682)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12722)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12768)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13502)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.
```

Comment: post your logcat code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566117/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-in-android

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code, but didn't got any error.

Comment: @ron then some problem is in your layout where you are adding that layout.

Comment: adding that layout inside another layout and then that xml using as view v

Comment: It works fine without any error in any view, I tried with the targetView as linearlayout and textview, its working fine.

Comment: please try targetView as linearlayout and view only

Comment: In my layout, I have taken layout inside there is another View, here I am passing the view as targetView.

Comment: in my xml file i m taking linearLayout that inside that linearLayout take another linearLayout and then pass asa target view

Comment: As per your saying, I tried with all, and it is working fine.

Comment: @ron StackOverFlowException occurs only when you use any statement recursively, please check with that.

Comment: Can you post where you are using and how?

Comment: i post a new question realated to bagde...pls check and help me